# Grabbing main image of the article

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, readability

I am using node-readability module to cleapup the articles. But in most of the cases, the main image of the article is not part of the grabbed content. So, I have made some changes in the helpers.js and readability.js files to grab the main image of the article ,removing it from the DOM object and adding the image to the articleContent eventually. The code:

helpers.js

```
var grabImage = module.exports.grabImage = function(document) {
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
var MINIMUM_SURFACE =  100*100;
 if (images.length > 0) { 
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
  var image = images[i];
   if ( image.getAttribute('data-src') ) {
                image.getAttribute('src') = image.getAttribute('data-src');
            }
            if ( image.getAttribute('data-lazy-src') ) {
                image.getAttribute('src') = image.getAttribute('data-lazy-    src');
            }
             if ( !image.getAttribute('src') ) {
                continue;
            }

            // //Compute surface
            // var w = image.getAttribute('width') || 1;
            // var h = image.getAttribute('height') || 1;
            // image.surface = w * h;
var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function() {
            var image.surface = this.width*this.height;
                }



             //Filter by size
             if ( image.surface > MINIMUM_SURFACE ) {
             var mainImageSrc = image.getAttribute('src');

                 //Resolve relative url
                 if (!mainImageSrc.match(/^http/)) {
                                 if (!image.ownerDocument.originalURL) {

                                      } else{
                      mainImageSrc = url.resolve(image.ownerDocument.originalURL, mainImageSrc);
                    }
                  }
                  image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
                break;
            }

   }
  }
  return mainImageSrc;
};
```

readability.js

```
var mainImgUrl = helpers.grabImage(this._document);
var img = this._document.createElement("IMG");
img.setAttribute('src',  mainImgUrl); 
articleContent.insertBefore(img, articleContent.childNodes[0] );
```

I am adding this above part of code in this function

```
Readability.prototype.getContent = function(notDeprecated) {
```

But, it' not working. The whole content is being grabbed ,but I'm getting this error

```
> Cleaning Conditionally [object HTMLDivElement] (image width-494:)
Cleaning Conditionally [object HTMLDivElement] (:)
fixed link
C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\routes\api.js:19
                var content = '<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>'+articl
e.title+'</title></head><body>' +article.content+'</body></html>';







 TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
    at C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\routes\api.js:19:78
    at Object.jsdom.env.done (C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\node_modules\node-readabi
    lity\src\readability.js:292:18)
    at C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\node_modules\node-readability\node_modules\jsdom
    \lib\jsdom.js:259:18
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
    typeerror: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined    at      C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\routes\api.js:19:78    at Object.jsdom.env.done (C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\node_modules\node-readability\src\readability.js:292:18)    at C:\Users\SAI\reader-rest\node_modules\node-readability\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom.js:259:18    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue.

I have posted the same on github . But No response. 
[https://github.com/luin/readability/issues/52](http://github%20link)

Comment: Usually this type of thing comes up when you grab an element that is actually NULL

Comment: But the articles I am testing have more than one image, @Lofus

Comment: Have you tried reducing the problem?  This is a lot of code.  StackOverflow isn't really a "fix my problem" site.  It helps if you show that you understand exactly where your problem is.

Comment: Yeah, the main problem here is with the "compute surface" part. Everything else is fine. I tried different options for that but none of them seem to give the result. @SandyGifford

Comment: Can you post the minimum amount of code to reproduce the issue?  Perhaps try creating a simplified version of your page on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).  Reducing often helps me solve the problem myself often, and if not you'll have something much easier for Stack peeps to read.